# “) Syntax error Invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ”

Tags: bash, shell

I have gone through all the possible similar questions on SO already & couldn't figure out the error.

```
echo $select_app
echo $bitmap
app_itx='echo $(($select_app & $bitmap))'
```

This script worked on machine with *bash version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin).*

but doesn't work on machine with *version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin).*

Both machines are 64-bit running windows 7 & windows 10 respectively.

output of script :

0x04

1

& 1“) Syntax error Invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ”

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: You have a carriage returns at the end of the lines, remove them.

Comment: `select_app` contains a carriage return. How is that variable set?

Comment: SOLVED : i was reading those variables from a text file. variables had carriage return. So I ran dos2unix variable_input_file.txt & it worked.